# Validación de formulario para no permitir números en nombres php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Avanzando en la validación de mi formulario en php me encuentro con un pequeño dilema, el cual consiste  cuando el usuario **travieso** , quiere hacer una broma de mal gusto o tirar abajo nuestra validación y al validar el nombre me ingresa caracteres numéricos y en este instante viendo mi código ocurriría esto, como podría evitar que el usuario ingrese en el nombre **Jo12** y muestre error, a continuación dejo mi código y una vez mas apelo a la comunidad para la ayuda en la solución de este pequeño dilema

```
if(empty($_POST["nombre"]))
{
    $error ='Ingresa un Nombre</br>';
}
else
{
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $nombre = filter_var($nombre,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $nombre = trim($nombre);
    if($nombre==''){
        $error .= 'Nombre Vacio</br>';
    }
    else if($nombre == is_numeric($nombre))
    {
        $error .= 'No se aceptan Números</br>';
    }
    else if(strlen($nombre)<4){
        $error .= 'Ingrese por favor un Nombre del Paciente</br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes realizar la validación de una vez sin necesidad de ir comprobando una a una las características del nombre usando un patrón regular haciendo uso de [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/es/preg_match) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/^[a-z]{4,}$/i", trim($_POST["nombre"])) !== 1) {
    $error = '
      El nombre del paciente es incorrecto:<br/>
      <ul>
        <li>Mínimo 4 caracteres</li>
        <li>Solo letras</li>
      </ul>
    ';
}
```

La expresión regular solo permite hacer uso de letras de la `a` a la `z`, excluyendo números, signos de puntuación, etc.

---

Si quieres mantener tu código, hacer las comprobaciones una a una y solo rechazar números (se permitirían signos de puntuación, etc), entonces la comprobación sería así:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST["nombre"])) {
    $error ='Ingresa un Nombre</br>';
} else {
    /* No necesitamos una variable transitoria para el contenido de $_POST["nombre"] */
    $_POST["nombre"] = filter_var($_POST["nombre"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $_POST["nombre"] = trim($_POST["nombre"]);
    if ($_POST["nombre"] == '') {
        $error .= 'Nombre Vacio</br>';
    } else if (preg_match("/[0-9]/", trim($_POST["nombre"])) === 1) {
        $error .= 'No se aceptan Números</br>';
    } else if (strlen($_POST["nombre"]) < 4) {
        $error .= 'Ingrese por favor un Nombre del Paciente</br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque es posible validar en php, he leído que lo mas recomendado es validar del lado del cliente antes de enviar la información al servidor, es decir validar con javascript, por lo que pienso que te convendría agregar una validación con antes de procesar en PHP.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="" id="nombre">
    <button class="button" id="validar">Validar</button>
    <p id="estado"></p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    const expresiones = {       
        nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{4,15}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.       
    } 
    var estado = document.getElementById("estado"); 

    document.getElementById("validar").addEventListener('click', () =>{
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value

        if (expresiones.nombre.test(nombre)) {
            estado.innerHTML = "Correcto";
      //Aqui deberias enviar el valor
        }else{
            estado.innerHTML = "Incorrecto";
      //aqui podrias decirle al usuario que el valor es incorrecto
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

En el ejemplo anterior la validación la hago con una expresión regular, en mi caso el script devuelve correcto o incorrecto si la validación es correcta o verdadera (el if devuelve true si se cumple la condición), en tu caso deberá enviar el valor a tu archivo php.

En caso de que la validación no se cumpla no se envia el valor con eso te aseguras de que la cadena contenga solo letras.

El código Javascript es una manera sencilla de ejemplificar una validación pero podrías hacerlo de otra forma, como mejor te convenga o como mejor se adapte a tu caso.

Comment: Tu afirmación **Aunque es posible validar en php, he leído que lo mas recomendado es validar del lado del cliente antes de enviar la información al servidor** es desafortunadamente incorrecta. Si bien es recomendable hacer ambas validaciones para avisar al usuario antes de enviar el formulario (y así evitar una petición POST innecesaria al servidor), JAMÁS hay que tomar como algo opcional ("es posible") hacer la comprobación del lado del servidor. La validación en el lado del servidor debe hacerse SIEMPRE.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias por tus comentario, me base en varios testimonios de devs que he visto en youtube, yo por lo regular llevo a cabo las 2 validaciones de igual manera.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias efectivamente era lo que estaba necesitando, un abrazo campeon!

Comment: Como te indica @OscarGarcia **la validación en el servidor es indispensable**. Y, todo post debe ser validado. En especial del lado del servidor se debe hacer **validaciones de seguridad** porque, del lado del cliente pueden ser realizadas acciones maliciosas y, en el camino, los envíos están expuestos a cambios. Te sugiero **desconfiar un poco de los youtubers** y buscar a cambio documentación oficial.

Comment: @quevedo gracias. te doy la razón justamente lo vi hace tiempo en un curso de youtube.